# Can we prevent laziness of Apache Spark Transformation?

Tags: apache-spark

Recently, one employer ask me a question that how can we prevent laziness of Apache Spark transformation. I know that we can persists and cache RDD data-set but in case of failure, it recompute from parent.

Can anyone please explain me, is there any function to stop the laziness of Spark transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, Spark *transformations* are lazy, and you must use an *action* in order to retrieve a concrete value out of them.

For example, the following transformations will always remain lazy:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> lineLengths = lines.map(s -> s.length());
```

Functions like `map` return RDDs, and you can only turn those RDDs into real values by performing actions, such as `reduce`:

```
int totalLength = lineLengths.reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
```

There is no flag that will make `map` return a concrete value (for example, a list of integers).

The bottom line is that you can use `collect` or any other Spark action to 'prevent the laziness' of a transformation:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt");
JavaRDD<Integer> lineLengths = lines.map(s -> s.length());
List<Integer> collectedLengths = lineLengths.collect()
```

Remember, though, the using `collect` on a large dataset will probably be a very bad practice, making your driver run out of memory.

Comment: Great answer. That means we could not prevent laziness of spark transformation until action is called.